#  Is there a squad mate limit?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, I am at a point were I am given the option to choose whether I want to take on a certain character as a squad mate. Doing so means I have 5 squad mates in total, which judging by the rendering of the selection screen seems like the max.

If I opt to choose this character, does this mean I will not be able to aquire further squad mates that otherwise might join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squad mates don't take away the place for any other possible squad mate. You have specific characters that are possible squad mates, you can't miss one due to accepting another squad mate.

The possible squad mates are:

> James Vega, Liara T'Soni, Garrus, EDI, Ashley/Kaidan, Tali, and Javik (a prothean from the DLC)

Answer (score 3):

No, each character slot is reserved for a unique character.  You can never hit a limit where you cannot recruit someone you want.